# Как извлечь элемент, который будет числом и длина которого будет больше 4х символов?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, итераторы

Например, есть строка:

```
а = 'qqqq 12qw3 12 12345'
```

Из неё необходимо извлечь элемент, который будет числом и длина которого будет больше 4-х символов.

Возможно, стоит использовать модуль `re`, но я не могу понять, как задать в нём условие выбора элемента по его длине.

Comment: Вероятно, так: `\d{4,}`.

Comment: Вы можете уточнить вопрос - что делать если таких чисел больше одного?

Comment: нужно вернуть первое найденное число по условию. Если такое число найдено - следует остановить итерацию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Строка:

```
In [56]: a = 'qqqq a987654xx321aa 12qw3 12 12345 zz 1234567'
```

Если необходимо вернуть только первое число длина которого больше 4х символов:

```
In [72]: re.search(r'\b(\d{5,})\b', a).group(0)
Out[72]: '12345'
```

Вариант **не использующий RegEx**:

```
In [68]: [s for s in a.split() if s.isdecimal() and len(s) > 4][0]
Out[68]: '12345'
```

Если необходимо вернуть **все** числа длина которых больше 4х символов:

```
In [57]: re.findall(r'\b(\d{5,})\b', a)
Out[57]: ['12345', '1234567']
```

или так, если считать  числом `987654` присутствующим в `a987654xx321aa`:

```
In [58]: re.findall(r'(\d{5,})', a)
Out[58]: ['987654', '12345', '1234567']
```

Comment: А если необходимо вернуть только первый встреченный по условию элемент?

Comment: @moffire, используйте `re.search()`.